# How to find JSON data based on what else is in the JSON object when duplicates exist?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm currently working on some data chart implementation on a website, and I have a JSON with some data, notably some ID numbers, some dates, and some datapoints. Because I have multiple dates under the same ID, I'm looking for a way to do what is essentially "Find the JSON object that has this ID and Month, then get the datapoint numbers from that object". Any help on how I would accomplish this? **Preferably without iteration, if possible, as the file is extremely large.** I'll include an example of what the JSON looks like:

```
[{
"ID" : "32",
"month" : "6",
"value" : "438"
},
{
"ID" : "32",
"month" : "5",
"value" : "223"
}
```

It should also be noted that the ID's aren't grouped together like this in the actual json, this is just an example. Also changing the json contents is not an option.

**Any help is greatly
appreciated, thank you!**

Answer (score 0):

In JS you could use `array.find`.

Something like `res = myArray.find(item => item["ID"] === "32" && item["month"] === "5")`.

Then res is the object your searching for.

---

If you want to accomplish lookups without any iteration you'd need to generate a data structure with unique keys, ie. make a new object with keys something like `id-month`.